# What is the best way to migrate my AWS RDS database (django)?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am in the process of setting up a Django deployment with a relational database service (RDS) from amazon (AWS).

I wonder what is the best way to update the database?

### What I did first

First I worked with container commands in project/.ebextensions/db-migrate.config:

```
container_commands:
  10_migrate:
    command: |
      source $PYTHONPATH/activate
      pipenv run python ./manage.py migrate
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: <app>.settings
```

I found that this resets the database every time. Also, I couldn't use the "createsuperuser" command because I can't interactively add a username and password (the logs give a similar error).

### What I do now:

I added my IP to the incoming rules from the database. Then I changed the database configuration in settings.py to the RDS endpoint.

Now I can use migration commands and I can create a superuser.
But is this the usual way? Can you tell me more about security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

I use migrations as I do in local development.
I simply added the configs to the database settings in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'xxxxxxx',
        'USER': 'xxxxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'environment.xxx.region.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Dont forget to not commit or push this / put the credentials in environment variables.